# make rectangle for moving objects insade android

Tags: java, android, performance

I want to make a rectangle to move object insade rectangle to other position on canvas, if anyone has any suggestion I will be very happy.

Here is an example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a paint application, so you should already have some code and you'd better post it, so we could use as the starting point.

You need to write a custom widget and intercept touch events to build the selection. Whenever the selection changes, you have to repaint the UI to draw the selection rectangle. When you detect the end of the gesture, the widget listens to touch events to decide if the user wants to move the selected area (the touch gestures started **inside** the selection) or deselect it and maybe start a new selection. Again, if the user is dragging the selection, every new touch event causes an `invalidate()` on the component.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slikar.slika&hl=sl this is my app and i want integrate into :) i hope i will make it

Comment: Here we tell you how to write code, don't write your code for you :) Often answers contain snippets or even small programs, but don't expect anyone to work on your app. I wrote how you could implement your requirements: if the answer can be improved I'll be happy to do it, but I'm not willing to write down a hundred lines of boilerplate code and debug it, because that it's your job :)

Comment: i like it your comment :D thats true :P

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it that you are displaying?
If it is a image you can dimply duplicate the pixels in a selected rectangle and temporary save it in a new image until the drag motion stop and then paint it back on the original image.